# How to send HTML Emails in Outlook.com

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook.com

I need help creating an HTML Email in Outlook.com. I looked in the settings and didn't see any information for this. I also searched online and in other Stackoverflow questions but couldn't really find the answer. My email is pretty simple, but each time to send it, all I see is the HTML code.

```html
<html>
  <body style="background-color:#f7f6f2; color:#555; margin:0;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr style="background-color:#f8f5e4;">
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
          <img src="absolute_path_to_my_image_here" alt="Email Logo" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 3px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;">
          <p style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">Hello <span style="color:#5e9773;">NAME</span>,</p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p><a href="my_url">Click here</a></p>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">Sincerely</p>
          <p>NAME</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you paste the html mark up into outlook.com editing window, where actually write the plain text e-mail?

Comment: Yes. I switched to plain-text and pasted it there.

Answer (score 2):

Neither Outlook.com (public site) nor Outlook 365 compose windows allow you to insert custom HTML content. You may only type your message and do basic formatting with the tools offered by compose view.

Comment: So what would I need to do to send an HTML email using Outlook.com? Is there even a way? There should be I would think.

Comment: If you want to do this once and use Outlook.com compose window, you are out of luck. If you need it on regular basis, depend on your requirements you may: 1. write a standalone application 2. write Office.js add-in; 3. find some tool which sends HTML content via Outlook.com; 4. Use another client (Thunderbird, etc.) which capable of sending custom HTML, connect to your Outlook.com account and send this message. Possibilities are endless.

Comment: One drawback to sending emails from an email client is that any of the limitations with that client will be reflected in the emails you send. If you send things from Outlook, I am hemmed in by the limitations of Outlook. I suggest another client, something like http://putsmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I have tried on Outlook 365 web + windows, and this worked for me.

1. Open html file in a browser
2. `ctrl + a` or `copy all` content (not the code, but the rendered HTML in browser)
3. `ctrl + v` or `paste` on the email new message body